# ejabberd mod_offline iphone pushed notifications

Tags: iphone, module, xmpp, push-notification, ejabberd

I'm currently developing a chat iPhone app and so far so good for regular configuration for the ejabberd server. I want to implement Push notification when the user is "offline" and to do this I just need to run a PHP script which gets a Token device and the text message to deliver via SSL to Apple's servers (the Apple part is done), my problem begins is that i have no clue how to implement this action to my ejabberd server? basically I just need to create an action on a received offline message i this possible. Can someone point me in the right direction. I have manage to begin writing some code for a new module but I get same error all the time when this module is called by the offline messages here's the code and the error.

module.erl

```
-module(mod_offline_push).
-behaviour(gen_mod).
-include("ejabberd.hrl").

-export([start/2, stop/1, send_notice/1]).

start(VHost,_Opts) ->
 ?INFO_MSG("Starting mod_offline_push Host: ~p", [VHost]),
 inets:start(),
    ssl:start(),
 ejabberd_hooks:add(offline_message_hook, VHost, ?MODULE,send_notice, 50), 
 ok.


stop(VHost) ->
    ?INFO_MSG("mod_offline_push stopping Host: ~p", [VHost]),
    ejabberd_hooks:delete(offline_message_hook, VHost, ?MODULE, send_notice, 50),
    ok.

send_notice(Packet) ->
 ?INFO_MSG("after http:",[]),
 Type = xml:get_tag_attr_s("type", Packet),
 FromS = xml:get_tag_attr_s("from", Packet),
 ToS   = xml:get_tag_attr_s("to", Packet),
 Body = xml:get_path_s(Packet, [{elem, "body"}, cdata]),
 if
 (Type == "chat") and (Body /= "") ->
 Sep = "&",
 Post = [
 "application=",ToS, Sep,
 "event=", FromS,Type, Sep,
 "description=", Body, Sep,
 "priority=-1" ],
 httpc:request(post, {"http://pushNotification/push", [], "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", list_to_binary(Post)},[],[]),
  ok;
 true ->
   ok
    end.
```

ERROR

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 2010-08-26 16:53:19 ===
E(<0.370.0>:ejabberd_hooks:190) : {undef,
                                   [{mod_offline_push,send_notice,
                                     [{jid,"userA","198.165.211.1",
                                       "2121731711282852044419503",
                                       "userA","198.165.211.206",
                                       "2121731711282852044419503"},
                                      {jid,"userB","198.165.211.1",
                                       [],"userB","198.165.211.1",[]},
                                      {xmlelement,"message",
                                       [{"type","chat"},
                                        {"to","userb@198.165.211.1"}],
                                       [{xmlelement,"body",[],
                                         [{xmlcdata,<<"Hello">>}]}]}]},
                                    {ejabberd_hooks,run1,3},
                                    {ejabberd_sm,route,3},
                                    {ejabberd_local,route,3},
                                    {ejabberd_router,route,3},
                                    {ejabberd_c2s,session_established,2},
                                    {p1_fsm,handle_msg,10},
                                    {proc_lib,init_p,5}]}
running hook: {offline_message_hook,
                  [{jid,"userA","198.165.211.1",
                       "2121731711282852044419503","userA",
                       "userA","2121731711282852044419503"},
                   {jid,"userB","198.165.211.1",[],"userB",
                       "198.165.211.1",[]},
                   {xmlelement,"message",
                       [{"type","chat"},{"to","userB@198.165.211.1"}],
                       [{xmlelement,"body",[],[{xmlcdata,<<"Hello">>}]}]}]}
```

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm working on the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

what the stacktrace says, is that there is no `send_notice` function in the `mod_offline_push`  that accepts *three* parameters (the two JIDs ones and the packet itself). The signature of your function doesn't match, as it expect only 1 argument.

The hook is expecting three-argument callbacks, so try with

```
send_notice(_From, _To, Packet).
```

Answer (score 2):

Please use the below blog , very informative.Their code works fine for me.

http://symmetricinfinity.com/2013/01/23/ios-push-notifications-from-ejabberd.html

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you remove the INFO_MSG lines in the source files.After that recompile and replace the beam files in the ejabberd folder.Don't forget to restart ejabberd.

Answer (score 0):

Ive used mod_interact which when offline calls an api. I have setup the api to send a push notification.